# Playwright trace getting an HTTP 500 from the service worker

Tags: playwright

I'm trying to open up a Playwright trace on trace.playwright.dev but I keep getting the error "Could not load trace from trace.zip. Make sure to upload a valid Playwright trace."

My teammates can open the same one, so it's something on my end. I'm getting this error in the response:

Request URL:
https://trace.playwright.dev/contexts?trace=blob%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Ftrace.playwright.dev%2Fa0c853e9-0ec0-48bd-8205-983a82749e35&traceFileName=trace+%281%29.zip
Request Method:
GET
Status Code:
500 Internal Server Error (from service worker)
Referrer Policy:

I took a look at my service worker and it looks ok on both Chrome and Edge (active and running, no errors, received < an hour ago). I've tried stopping and starting and unregistering\registering the worker. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Please share a [mcve].